# Proving integral inequality for all $f\in H^1(D)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

LET $D\subset\mathbb R^n$ and $s\ge 0$ be some constant. I want to show that there exists a constant $C$ such that
[image]
for all $f\in H^1(D)$ that satisfies $s\le \sharp\{t \mid f(t)=0\}$.

Can someone please give me some ideas?

Comment: Hey, I recognize this problem. Not an exact duplicate because $D≠B(0,1)$ but its close. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247682/evans-pde-problem-5-15-poincaré-inequality-for-functions-with-large-zero-set

Comment: Another answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562620/the-l2-norm-of-a-function-bounded-by-l2-norm-of-its-weak-derivative-in-uni/2564840#2564840)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll outline the ideas of an argument that I think should do the job:

- By contradiction assume that such a constant doesn't exist.
  You can find a sequence $f_{k}$ in $H^1(D)$ s.t. 
  $$\int_Df_k^2> k \int_D |\nabla f_k|^2$$
  and with $f_{k}=0$ on a set of measure $\geq s$.
- Set $g_k=\frac{f_{k}}{||f_{k}||^2_{L^2(D)}}$. You have $||g_{k}||^2_{L^2(D)}=1$ and 
  $\nabla g_k=\frac{\nabla f_{k}}{||f_{k}||^2_{L^2(D)}}$.
- $$1=||g_{k}||^2_{L^2(D)}>\ k\ \  \frac{\int_D |\nabla f_k|^2}{||f_{k}||^2_{L^2(D)}}=k\ \  \int_D |\nabla g_k|^2.$$
- Using Rellich-Kondrachov you get a subsequence of $g_k$ (we will still denote it $g_k$) which converges in $L^2(D)$ to some $g$.
- You have $1=||g||^2_{L^2(D)}$ and you can show (easy) that the gradient of $g$ is $0$. Thus $g$ is constant and since it is $0$ on a set of measure $\geq s$, it must be identically $0$. But since the norm of $g$ is $1$ we get a contradiction. ($g=0$ on a set of measure $\geq s$ because passing to a further subsequence you have also conergence a.e.).

Just a note: I'm not sure the result is true if you don't require D to be connected.

Comment: It wont be true for disconnected $D$ just like normal Poincaré with essentially the same counterexample, just make $f=0$ on a large set like $B(0,100 s^{1/n})$ and make it constant $≠0$ on a disjoint component, so $LHS > RHS = 0$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor as I suspected, thanks